# Web service beginner, using Android

Tags: android, soap, web-services, connection

I read the first tutorials today on SOAP webs ervices and I'd like to create my own service, e.g. a java class Person that should be my web service. I don't know what application do I need to store this web service for accesing it as a test, and neither how to access it from ANDROID.

Please help me with this.

All the best

Answer (score 1):

So your real question is how to build a Web Service. If you want an Android App to use your Web Service it will be easier if the Web Service is RESTful. Here are some tutorials on [Building RESTful Web Services](http://www.xfront.com/REST-Web-Services.html). Why don't you try that out and come back when you have more detailed questions.

Comment: Thanks for your site, I understood REST better